# GeoNetwork CSW Harvest Error - "gmd:MD_MetaData, csw: record" is not a valid value for QName

Tags: geonetwork, csw

I'm trying to run a CSW Harvest in GeoNetwork, but I get this error:

```
"gmd:MD_MetaData, csw: record"  is not a valid value for QName
```

I'm using GeoNetwork 2.10.3 on Windows 7 64 bit and GeoServer 2.6.2

Comment: Can you post more details on the error? Can you check the logfile and write the full exception trace?

Can you also post the harvester configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
"gmd:MD_MetaData, csw: record"
```

Well, the error message is correct the quoted text is not a valid QName, as we can see from its definition:

```
QName              ::=   PrefixedName | UnprefixedName
PrefixedName       ::=   Prefix ':' LocalPart
UnprefixedName     ::=   LocalPart
Prefix             ::=   NCName
LocalPart          ::=   NCName
```

and

```
NCName             ::=   Name - (Char* ':' Char*)  /* An XML Name, minus the ":" */
```

*Reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName*

i.e.

We have a `PrefixedName`, the prefix is `gmd`, we have an `:`, the `LocalPart` is therefore  `MD_MetaData, csw: record` which should be an `NCName` but it is invalid because there is a colon after the csw.